# Table View UI error: Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, user-interface, xcode6

On the last question I asked about the code error in my animal table view project, now I finished the initial coding, but my UI turned really strange. It is missing the first letter of each animal name and the table view prototype cell.
For example, *amel* should be camel and *hinoceros* should be rhinoceros.
Is this a bug from the code here?

```
import UIKit

class AnimalTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var animalsDict = [String: [String]] ()
var animalSelectionTitles = [String] ()

let animals = ["Bear", "Black Swan", "Buffalo", "Camel", "Cockatoo", "Dog", "Donkey", "Emu", "Giraffe", "Greater Rhea", "Hippopotamus", "Horse", "Koala", "Lion", "Llama", "Manatus", "Meerkat", "Panda", "Peacock", "Pig", "Platypus", "Polar Bear", "Rhinoceros", "Seagull", "Tasmania Devil", "Whale", "Whale Shark", "Wombat"]

func createAnimalDict() {
    for animal in animals {
        let animalKey = animal.substringFromIndex(advance(animal.startIndex, 1))
        if var animalValues = animalsDict[animalKey] {
            animalValues.append(animal)
            animalsDict[animalKey] = animalValues
        } else {
            animalsDict[animalKey] = [animal]
        }
    }
    animalSelectionTitles = [String] (animalsDict.keys)
    animalSelectionTitles.sort({ $0 < $1})
    animalSelectionTitles.sort( { (s1:String, s2:String) -> Bool in
        return s1 < s2
    })
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    createAnimalDict()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return animalSelectionTitles.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section:Int)  -> String? {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return animalSelectionTitles[section]

}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    let animalKey = animalSelectionTitles[indexPath.section]
    if let animalValues = animalsDict[animalKey] {
        cell.textLabel?.text = animalValues[indexPath.row]
        let imageFileName = animalValues[indexPath.row].lowercaseString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("", withString: "_", options: nil, range: nil)
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named:imageFileName)
    }
    return cell
}
```

}

Comment: Have you checked that `animalsDict` contains what you expect? And shouldn't it be `substringToIndex` instead of `substringFromIndex` as already suggested in an answer to your previous question? Did you set a breakpoint in `titleForHeaderInSection ` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and used the **debugger** to check where the "wrong" names come from?

Answer (score 1):

So far I can say the error is in your `createAnimalDict()` method. In the line

```
let animalKey = animal.substringFromIndex(advance(animal.startIndex, 1))
```

exchange the second parameter in advance to 0 so it be:

```
let animalKey = animal.substringFromIndex(advance(animal.startIndex, 0))
```

In fact I don't really know what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

In this method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section:Int)  -> String? {
    // Return the number of rows in the section. (THIS COMMENT IS INCORRECT)
    return animalSelectionTitles[section]
}
```

You are returning the title for each section. However your `animalSelectionTitles[index]` contains the animal name without the first letter due to its construction in `createAnimalDict`

Use the animal array instead for providing the full animal names:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section:Int)  -> String? {         
     return animals[section]
}
```

However note that due to the removal of the first letter you might have two animals mapping to the same key so if not necessary use the entire animal name as the key.